# Unable to write BestCommentId on FeedItem in test class

Tags: apex, failing-tests, feeditem, feedcomment

I am trying to write a test class to test an Apex class that uses FeedItem object. The Apex class checks if the FeedItem record has a BestCommentId and does some actions. A snippet of the test data that I am creating is as follows -

```
FeedItem fi = new FeedItem(Title = 'Feed Title',ParentId = parentId,Type = 'QuestionPost');
insert fi;
FeedComment fc = new FeedComment(CommentBody = 'Comment Body',FeedItemId = fi.Id);
insert fc;
fi.BestCommentId = fc.Id;
update fi;
```

I get an exception on `fi.BestCommentId = fc.Id` line that says `Field is not writeable: FeedItem.BestCommentId`. Is there a way to do this? Especially without using `seeAllData=true`.

Comment: The field itself is not updateable and thus I don't think you can really update it from test class either. There's [an idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CLZfQAO) to allow the ability to set this field.

Comment: @JayantDas - Thank you. I've upvoted the idea.